# What are spring-boot supported versions for log4j?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, log4j, log4j2

Can I know about what are the `spring-boot` supported versions for `log4j`. Because I use `spring-boot version 1.5.9.` It is already support for `log4j2` and I want to know what is the latest version that support for `log4j`.

Answer (score 2):

All latest versions of `Spring Boot` supports `log4j2`.

Current version of `Spring Boot 2.0.0` supports `log4j2 version 2.10.0`. You can verify other dependency versions from [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#appendix-dependency-versions).